# Infinitely Horizontally scrolling set of divs within container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a strip of logos that when one is selected reveals a quote from that customer. When a logo is selected, it should go to the left side of the strip and stay there. I got that to work.

My problem is making the logos go on forever.

As the divs of the logos go outside of their container, I'm trying to remove them and then recreate them on the other side of the strip, so that the logos can keep going on and on and on. However, it is not working very well.

This is the html:

```
<div class="logo-strip">
                <div id="logo-1" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-2" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-3" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-4" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-5" class="logo">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Safeway_Logo.svg/1280px-Safeway_Logo.svg.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-6" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-7" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-8" class="logo">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Safeway_Logo.svg/1280px-Safeway_Logo.svg.png">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 div.logo-strip {
 display: flex;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden; }

div.logo-strip div.logo {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 112.5px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .4;
  transition: .5s; }

    div.logo-strip div.logo img {
    object-fit: contain; }

  div.logo-strip div.selected-logo {
  opacity: 1; }
```

Now here is my js:

```
( function( $ ) {


$('div#quote-1').removeClass('hidden');
$('div#quote-1').animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 500);
$('div#logo-1').addClass('selected-logo');

$('div.logo').click(function() {

    $('div.logo').removeClass('selected-logo');
    $(this).addClass('selected-logo');

    var logo_offset = $(this).offset().left - $('div.logo').first().offset().left;
    var negative_offset = logo_offset * -1;

    var strip_offset = $('div.logo-strip').offset().left - $('div.logo').first().offset().left;

    if (strip_offset >  100) {

        var to_be_cloned = $('div.logo').slice(0, 3);
        to_be_cloned.remove();
        $('div.logo').last().after(to_be_cloned);

    }

    console.log(strip_offset);
    console.log(to_be_cloned);

    $('div.logo').css({'transform' : 'translateX(' + negative_offset + 'px)'});

    var logo_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var logo_id_trimmed = logo_id.substr(5);

    $('div.customer-quote').addClass('hidden');
    $('div.customer-quote').css({'opacity' : '0'});
    $('div#quote-' + logo_id_trimmed).removeClass('hidden');
    $('div#quote-' + logo_id_trimmed).animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 500);
});

} )( jQuery );
```

Basically I've been trying to make it so that after the first logo gets a certain distance away from the `div.logo-strip` container element, then it removes that logo `div` and recreates it at the end of the logo `divs`. It sort of works but it is janky as hell. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

First, everything was moving around strangle because I was deleting the divs on one end of the set and putting them on the other end, causing everything to shift around. What I needed to do was clone the divs and put them at the end, so I was just adding divs on the end, and not removing them from the beginning at all.

Second, I needed to get the index of the previously selected div and the newly selected div and use them to create the slice numbers.

Third, you need to move the whole chain of divs by a measurement of the newly selected div's offset left minus the first div's offset left.

Fourth, you need to start out with extra divs trailing outside of the area on end. If you don't have that then it will move weird at the beginning.

Here is the new JS:

```
$('div.logo').click(function() {
    var previously_selected = $('div.selected-logo');
    var newly_selected = $(this);
    var number_of_previous_selection = $('div.logo').index(previously_selected);
    var number_of_new_selection = $('div.logo').index(newly_selected);
    var selection_distance = number_of_previous_selection - number_of_new_selection;

    $('div.logo').removeClass('selected-logo');
    $(this).addClass('selected-logo');

    var logo_offset = $(this).offset().left - $('div.logo').first().offset().left;
    var negative_offset = logo_offset * -1;
    var strip_offset = $('div.logo-strip').offset().left - $('div.logo').first().offset().left;

    var to_be_cloned = $('div.logo').slice(number_of_previous_selection, number_of_new_selection).clone(true);
    $('div.logo-strip').append(to_be_cloned);
    $('div.logo').css({'transform' : 'translateX(' + negative_offset + 'px)'});

    console.log(number_of_new_selection);
    console.log(number_of_previous_selection);
    console.log(negative_offset);

    var logo_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var logo_id_trimmed = logo_id.substr(5);

    $('div.customer-quote').addClass('hidden');
    $('div.customer-quote').css({'opacity' : '0'});
    $('div#quote-' + logo_id_trimmed).removeClass('hidden');
    $('div#quote-' + logo_id_trimmed).animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 500);


});
```

And then the HTML:

```
<div class="quote-and-title">
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-1">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-2">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-3">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-4">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-5">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-6">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-7">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-8">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-9">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-10">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-11">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="customer-quote hidden" id="quote-12">
                    <p class="customer-text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
                    dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                    minim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
                    <p class="customer-title">John Smith, Facility Manager</p>
                </div>
                <div class="title has-red-divider-uptop">
                    <p>What The Industry is Saying</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="logo-strip">

                <div id="logo-1" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-2" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-3" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-4" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-5" class="logo">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Safeway_Logo.svg/1280px-Safeway_Logo.svg.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-6" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-7" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-8" class="logo">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Safeway_Logo.svg/1280px-Safeway_Logo.svg.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-9" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-10" class="logo">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Safeway_Logo.svg/1280px-Safeway_Logo.svg.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-11" class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.henningsen.com/wp-content/themes/henningsen-cold-storage/images/logo-emboss.png">
                </div>
                <div id="logo-12" class="logo">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Safeway_Logo.svg/1280px-Safeway_Logo.svg.png">
                </div>

            </div>
```